# How to use pivot when you want to combine three field in one category

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have data in this format

```
Skill   Min  Ideal  Max
==========================
 C++    0      1    1
```

I want to display it like this

```
Criteria    C++
```

=================

```
 Min          0
 Ideal        1
 Max          1
```

I am confused at the part where i wan to convert Min , Ideal and Max into criteria.

Comment: you are looking for `unpivot`. Also, tag the question with the dbms being used.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Check for TempTable existence, drop if exists

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Stack') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Stack;
END
GO

--Create Table

CREATE TABLE #Stack
([Skill] VARCHAR(10)
 , [Min] INT
 , [Ideal] INT
 , [Max] INT);

--Insert Sample data

 INSERT INTO #Stack([Skill], [Min], [Ideal], [Max])
 SELECT 'C++', 0, 1, 1;

--Check inserted data

SELECT [Skill], [Min], [Ideal], [Max] FROM #Stack;

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Skill   Min     Ideal   Max
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
C++     0       1       1 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

--Use Unpivot to get desired result

SELECT u.Criteria, u.[C++]
FROM #Stack
UNPIVOT
(
    [C++] FOR [Criteria] IN ([Min], [Ideal], [Max])
) u;

++++++++++++++++++
Criteria    C++
++++++++++++++++++
Min         0
Ideal       1
Max         1
++++++++++++++++++
```

However, what if add 1 more skill?

```
 INSERT INTO #Stack([Skill], [Min], [Ideal], [Max])
 SELECT 'C#', 1, 1, 1;
```

Our data is now

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Skill   Min     Ideal   Max
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
C++     0       1       1
C#      1       1       1   
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And the same Unpivot query from above, gives us the following result

```
++++++++++++++++++
Criteria    C++
++++++++++++++++++
Min         0
Ideal       1
Max         1
Min         1
Ideal       1
Max         1
++++++++++++++++++
```

So to solve that case, I used some dynamic sql as shown below:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @pivcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Get dynamic list of Skill
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Skill)
                      FROM #Stack
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

--Build dynamic list of columns pre-pend with alias piv.
SELECT @pivcols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',piv.' + QUOTENAME(Skill)
                         FROM #Stack
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                           , 1, 1, '');

--Build query for Unpivot and Pivot
SELECT @query = '
SELECT piv.Criteria, ' + @pivcols + '
FROM
(
    SELECT Skill, [Min], Ideal, [Max]
    FROM #Stack
) d
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [Criteria] IN ([Min],[Ideal],[Max])
) AS unpiv
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) 
    FOR [Skill] IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS piv'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

This should now give us the following result

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
Criteria    C#  C++
+++++++++++++++++++++++
Ideal       1   1
Max         1   1
Min         1   0
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

You can read more about this and another method `Cross Apply` [from the dba.StackExchange answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122670/72658) by user [Julien Vavasseur](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/72048/julien-vavasseur).

I also referenced the [Books Online PIVOT/UNPIVOT usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).